# What does x.ar mean for an R variable x?

Tags: r

As a beginner of R, I can't understand some code in this webpage:
https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Autoregressive-Moving-Average-ARMA-p-q-Models-for-Time-Series-Analysis-Part-1

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- w <- rnorm(100)
> for (t in 2:100) x[t] <- 0.6*x[t-1] + w[t]
> x.ar <- ar(x, method = "mle")
> x.ar$order
```

I think *x* is a variable(vector?). But what is *x.ar* and *x.ar$order*? Are they some fields of *x* just like the field of a struct of C/C++?

Comment: ``x.ar`` is simply the object name and ``x.ar$order`` is to select ``order`` in ``x.ar``. The person that write this article simply named the new ``x`` to ``x.ar`` since he is using the ``ar()`` function. It is simply for descriptive purpose.

Comment: it has no special meaning here. find-and-replace `x.ar` with `this_is_my_variable_x` and the code will run the same

Comment: more generally . in R is used in _calls_ (i.e. functions) to denote S3 methods. it's a somewhat strange system if you have experience with other languages so I won't be able to summarize here but other resources should be easy to find

Comment: Whenever you see `blah <- ...` that means create a variable named `blah` (if it doesn't exist already) and set the value of `blah` to `...`. So `x.ar <- ar(x, method = "mle")` means create a variable, call it `x.ar`, and give it the value of whatever `ar(x, method = "mle")` produces. (Which, if we look at `?ar`, is an auto-regreessive time series model.)

Comment: R *doesn't* use `.` in names for structure like many other programming languages - it uses `$` (and sometimes `@`). So `x.ar` is just a name, but `x.ar$order` is the `order` element of the `x.ar` variable. If you look at the `?ar` help page, the **Value** section tells you all the elements of the `ar` object, and will describe what `order` is.

Comment: @Gregor Can you tell me when R is using ``@`` ? I was not aware of this!

Comment: @Gainz to access slots in S4 classes. See, e.g., `?slot`. (`object@name` is syntactical sugar for `slot(object, name)`)

Comment: Gainz, MichaelChirico, Gregor: OK, I see. So it is simple to understand what they mean with your explanations. Thanks for your kind help!